# p:spinner inside datatable inside ui:repeat not working as expected

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've got this setup where you can open a popup, select multiple items and a spinner for every item appears allowing you to define the number of items.
There can also be multiple number of such popups. I use the following setup:

view.xhtml:

```
...
<ui:repeat id="iter">
    <p:dialog id="dPopUp" widgetVar="#{str.index}">
        <ui:decorate template="/views/popup.xhtml" />
    </p:dialog>
</ui:repeat>
<p:commandButton value="SELECT" type="button" onclick="PF(#{str.index}).show(); setCurrentList(#{str.index});" />
...
```

popup.xhtml:

```
...
<p:dataTable id="popupList" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
    <p:column>
        <p:spinner id="spinIt" value="#{uiBean.currentList.get(rowIndex).spinnerValue}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
...
```

Whole thing works like charm for one popup, but as soon as you save data on that popup and open a another popup and try to add items, you get a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`. Somewhy the getter for currentList is called before setCurrentList method when opening a new popup, but newly opened popup has no spinners because nothing has been selected yet. So i'm guessing this is the cause of the exception because the list is originally empty. Why does it even call the getter when i try to select an item if there are no spinners in the selected popup? It doesn't do that upon opening first popup.
Basic scheme of setup:
[image]